# Link to a question without it appearing as linked?

Tags: support, linked-questions

Over on Stack Overflow (but relevant to all Stack Exchange sites), specifically *[Comparing objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132255)*, I posted a comment to explain my previous "removing invalid dupe flag" comment.

In this explanation, I link to the question that was used as a "dupe flag", explaining that it was completely irrelevant and hence the removal.

But now, because I linked to the irrelevant question, it's now appearing in the "Linked" list of links, which makes it look relevant...

Is there any way to link to the irrelevant question as part of my explanation, but to suppress its appearance in the Linked list so as not to pollute it?

Comment: Linked != Relevant but yeah, you got a point here.